# Interpolating (kriging) in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, kriging, masking

I would like to interpolate with kriging data points from one shapefile that should fill out the Space of another shapefile i am using as a boundary.

I have set this boundary under Geoprocessing --> Environments --> Raster analysis, as i have understood this should be the best way to both limit the extent of the interpolation as well as force the interpolation to cover the extent of this layer.

When i try to carry out the interpolation, it fails and i get the following error messages regarding :

- the Grid IO : 010429,
- grid expression : 010067
- and variance : 010079.

I have no idea how to fix this. i am sure the data is not corrupted, otherwise it wouldnt show in ArcMap 10.3.

i've tried increasing the cell size for the last error, also to no avail.

Comment: Does it work if you don't set a boundary ?

Comment: It does work without a boundary, but then i discovered that i need the interpolation to be inside of the municipality I want to model, hence my Desire to force the interpolation to extend to this other shapefile (and also stay within it).

Comment: I can see that the boundaries of the krig test seem to be within the file that contains the data... which is of course obvious! Do i need to first connect these two shapefiles, i.e. force the datafile to have the same boundaries as the municipality file? I thought that was the purpose of using a mask, from my understanding of its description on the ESRI webpage...
Thanks for your help, by the way!

Comment: And if i need to combine the data somehow, is there a good suggestion for the best way? One shapefile is polygon, the other contains the point data...
So probably this is the join data based on spatial location. but here i don't follow the wizard, where it asks whether i want the attributes (from the point shapefile which i will join to the polygon file) to either be summarized (e.g. average, sum, etc, which doesnt make sense) or i choose the other option, but perhaps this makes sense only if there are multiple polygons, but i have only one?

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, however...